# jQuery Datatables & Grails with large data

Tags: javascript, grails, datatables

I am using datatables to display & filter data of a grails application.

The data is not huge, `8000 rows` at the moment.
I am building the table with a normal .gsp file and a

```
<g:each in dataset>
    <tr>
        <td> ${datainstance.property1} </td>
        <td> ${datainstance.property2} </td>
        <td> ${datainstance.property3} </td>
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

**problem**

grails is rendering the table at first: 800 rows, before datatables kicks in. this means the user sees:

```
1) table getting longer and longer
2) table shrinking and shrinking
3) filters appearing
```

once everything is loaded filtering is smooth and fast.

what can i do to reduce the loading time & to not let the user see a table building itself up?

Comment: Paginate your data !!!

Comment: @LalitAgarwal i am actually using the pagination from datatables. if i paginate within grails `get([max:params.max, offset:params.offset])` the datasource for datatables will only contain `max-offset` elements which are not all :/

Comment: you can try [easyGrid plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/easygrid) which is also support dataTables. I am currently using this plugin, it also support pagination and filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with everything on the datatable side then you need to do it with AJAX call:

http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/

http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
  "url": "data.json",
  "type": "POST"
 }
} );
```

It will load your datatable first and will show "Loading" till all your data gets populated in datatable.

Hopefully that will solve your problem

Comment: ill give that a go either today or tomorrow and let you know, thank you for the effort.

Comment: this solved my problem brilliantly after a bit of struggling setting it up! thank you :)